# php-finding next array value in a for-loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

PHP question.
Running the values of an array through a for loop, and need to find the next value, 
as a reference based on the value currently in the loop.

I created the array below:

```
$item_number: A12345-AFA-21-AEA-22-APA-23
$items = explode("-", $item_number);
```

i'm using a for loop that starts at AFA:

```
for ($i=1; $i<$itemcount; $i++)
```

setting the current loop value to $item.

```
$item = $items[$i];
```

How do I get the next value in the array?
here is what seems the most logical to me.. but doesn't seem to work.

```
$next = $items[$i+1]
```

How do I get to the next array value?

Comment: Why don't you use a `foreach` loop?

Comment: `$items[$i+1]` is the right approach. What do you get when using this?

Comment: Your code looks broadly correct, but your loop should probably execute while `$i<$itemcount-1`. Do you get an error message? If so, please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, maybe just add isset($items[$i+1]) or if($i < $itemcount - 1) before using it, because on last element it will crash..

Comment: < $itemcount should be fine, since it will stop looping if it equals itemcount

Comment: If $i+1 is used as array key in loop, it should be that way imho - he will be out of index on last element.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but keep in mind that an array starts at 0 not 1, so you need to change it to:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$itemcount; $i++){
    $item = $items[$i];
    $next = $items[$i+1];
}
```